# Get rid of java.util.NoSuchElementException Error

Tags: java

I would like to know the proper way to ask for user's input in Java until the user gives an acceptable value.

I thought that new Scanner(System.in); is the best way but I get that error.

```
   int myValue = 0;
   int myNumber;

   do {

   System.out.println("Enter a Positive Number: ");
   Scanner scanNumber = new Scanner(System.in);
   myNumber = scanNumber.nextLine();
   scanNumber.close();

   //Check for acceptable inputs

   }while(myValue<=0);
```

Comment: Read javadoc on usage of `hasNext` methods: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're closing the `Scanner` (`scanNumber.close();`) which closes the underlining stream so at the second iteration you're trying to create a new `Scanner` using a closed stream hence the exception.

Just remove the `scanNumber.close();` statement and this exception shouldn't occur anymore.

Beside that, the code that you've posted tries to store a `String` in an `int` variable (`myNumber = scanNumber.nextLine();`) so I guess this isn't the code that produced the exception since this won't compile.

Comment: Does OP also need to check `hasNextLine`?